# OutOfMemoryError exception when reading Avro files on GCS

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I exported the BigQuery dataset whose size is about 650GB to Avro files on GCS and run dataflow program to process these Avro files. However, the OutOfMemoryError exception is encountered even if only one Avro file whose size is about 1.31GB is processed.

I got the following error message, and it seems like that the exception stems from AvroIO and Avro library:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readString(BinaryDecoder.java:260)
        at org.apache.avro.io.ValidatingDecoder.readString(ValidatingDecoder.java:107)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readString(GenericDatumReader.java:348)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readString(GenericDatumReader.java:341)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:154)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:152)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:177)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:148)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:139)
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.next(DataFileStream.java:233)
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.next(DataFileStream.java:220)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.AvroReader$AvroFileIterator.next(AvroReader.java:143)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.AvroReader$AvroFileIterator.next(AvroReader.java:113)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.ReaderUtils.readElemsFromReader(ReaderUtils.java:37)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.AvroIO.evaluateReadHelper(AvroIO.java:638)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.AvroIO.access$000(AvroIO.java:118)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.AvroIO$Read$Bound$1.evaluate(AvroIO.java:294)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.AvroIO$Read$Bound$1.evaluate(AvroIO.java:290)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner$Evaluator.visitTransform(DirectPipelineRunner.java:611)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformTreeNode.visit(TransformTreeNode.java:200)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformTreeNode.visit(TransformTreeNode.java:196)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:109)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:204)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner$Evaluator.run(DirectPipelineRunner.java:584)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner.run(DirectPipelineRunner.java:328)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner.run(DirectPipelineRunner.java:70)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:145)
        at com.htc.studio.bdi.dataflow.ActTranGenerator.main(ActTranGenerator.java:224)
```

Any suggestion for this exception?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the DirectPipelineRunner, which is running on your local machine. This mode runs entirely in memory, and is best used for testing or developing over small datasets. Direct pipeline execution may require keeping multiple copies of your data in memory (depending on your exact algorithm), so I would not recommend using it for large files. Instead, specify --runner=BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner to run via the Dataflow service.

---

This information isn't directly related to your situation, but may be helpful to others encountering OOMs when using the DataflowPipelineRunner or BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner:

OutOfMemory exceptions can be tricky to diagnose because:
(1) The location at which memory runs out may not be the location that is consuming the bulk of the memory.
(2) Because of the way in which Dataflow optimizes your pipeline, ParDos from different logical components of your pipeline may be executing together in the same JVM. 
So you may have to look for colocated DoFns in the worker logs to figure out which DoFn is actually hogging all the memory.

A common cause of OOMs is processing a KV> with a DoFn that tries to keep all the Vs in memory (for example in a Collection). That won't scale to situations that may have lots of values with the same key.

If there's no algorithmic issue and you just need workers with a little more memory, you can adjust the VM instance type with something like:
--workerMachineType=n1-standard-4

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Frances! I forgot that DirectPipelineRunner is supposed to run on the local machine. After changing the runner to BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner, I can generate output records by extracting some fields from input records. However, when running the complete program, I encountered another OutOfMemoryError exception: Java heap space even if  --workerMachineType=n1-standard-4 is given. How can I know the java heap setting and specify java heap option in Dataflow service?